# Android: know when android stop execute getView() on ListView

Tags: android, listview

I know Android execute 2 times (or sometimes even more) the `getView()` method of the adapter in order to draw the ListView correctly. I would like to know (or get notified) when it stops execute that method.

Why? The rows of my list are animated when user swipes on one of them. If the user swipes before Android has finished execute `getView()`, the animation is executed on the first row instead of the row touched by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load **ListView in background AsyncTask**. And during that time you can show `progress dialog` on the screen so user is not able to do any action on your screen.

Check this **Reference** :

[Load ListView in background AsyncTask](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/load-listview-in-background-asynctask.html)

Hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: It's be a solution even if see the progress dialog every time it's a bit annoying...btw thanks

Comment: @DanieleVitali if you dont want to show progress dialog then you can set some flag at `preexecute` method with `false` and make it `true` from `postexecute` method to restrict user swipes actions. This can be one of the way.

Comment: Yes actually I was thinking the same thing after I've written the comment. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no last getView()

When you are scrolling in a list, for each item that will become visible a getView() will be called. EVEN when it has already been on screen. I believe you are not detecting the list view item click properly.

Comment: I didn't know about that, thanks. Btw, I think the detection works properly. I'm using the ListView.pointToPosition() in order to get the number of row touched and I pass the coordinates of the event fired as parameters.